# Edit old commit messages using LibGit2Sharp

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

Is it possible to edit the commit message of a commit that is not the latest one using libgit2sharp?

Comment: _"replace a specific word in all commit messages in a repository."_ - You probably want to find out how to do a `git filter-branch` with the library at hand. Example of `filter-branch` usage: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/ . Note that this will rewrite your entire branch since every commit has to be rewritten.

Comment: I just realized that this is a bad example so I removed it. My use case is to go through all commits in a repo, generate a text from the diff (this part works already) and set it as the commit message. @cubrr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analogy to `git filter-branch` is `Repository.Refs.RewriteHistory`.

As an example, lets rewrite all commit messages that contain `foo` by replacing `foo` with `StackoverFlow`:

```
repo.Refs.RewriteHistory (new RewriteHistoryOptions {
    OnError = OnError, 
    OnSucceeding = OnSucceeding,
    CommitHeaderRewriter = c =>
    CommitRewriteInfo.From (c, c.Message.Replace ("foo", "StackOverflow")),
}, commitsToRewrite);
```

**Pre-rewrite:**

```
git log --oneline
b859690 Commit foo 3
327f702 Commit foo 2
75ac0b8 Commit foo 1
```

**Post-rewrite:**

```
git log --oneline
dc156e3 Commit StackOverflow 3
587f6c3 Commit StackOverflow 2
894361f Commit StackOverflow 1
```

**Note:** As you will see in the above log output, the SHAs have changed, just as they would via `git filter-branch` so you will have to *force* any pushes to remotes...

I would *highly* recommend going through the test fixture [`FilterBranchFixture.cs`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FilterBranchFixture.cs) as this is the best documentation of `RewriteHistory` and you will find the different rewrite classes, like rewriting parents of a commit, being used here and how errors are handled...

> [WARNING](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)! The rewritten history will have different object names for
>   all the objects and will not converge with the original branch. You
>   will not be able to easily push and distribute the rewritten branch on
>   top of the original branch. Please do not use this command if you do
>   not know the full implications, and avoid using it anyway, if a simple
>   single commit would suffice to fix your problem. (See the "RECOVERING
>   FROM UPSTREAM REBASE" section in git-rebase(1) for further information
>   about rewriting published history.)

**Cut/Paste Example:**

```
using System;
using LibGit2Sharp;

namespace gitrewrite
{

    class MainClass
    {
        private static bool succeeding;
        private static Exception error;

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var repo = new Repository ("/Users/sushi/code/XamTests/RepoTestBed");

            // Assuming you might pre-filter, but for this example take ALL commits
            var commitsToRewrite = repo.Commits;

            repo.Refs.RewriteHistory (new RewriteHistoryOptions {
                OnError = OnError, 
                OnSucceeding = OnSucceeding,
                CommitHeaderRewriter = c =>
                    CommitRewriteInfo.From (c, c.Message.Replace ("foo", "StackOverflow")),
            }, commitsToRewrite);   
        }

        private static Action OnSucceeding {
            get {
                succeeding = false;
                return () => succeeding = true;
            }
        }

        private static Action<Exception> OnError {
            get {
                error = null;
                return ex => error = ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol, Thanks! ;-) I had to write slew of custom filter *Rewriter's for a contract job, I know know that code reaaaalllllyyyy well. :-p

Comment: Great answer! I had to add a `message:` in `CommitRewriteInfo.From (c, message: c.Message.Replace ("foo", "StackOverflow")),` to make it work.